# vsftpd: Passwordless authentication to different directory

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I am configuring a vsftpd server and the requirements are:

1. I need a user `resourcesadmin` with home directory `/var/www/resources` with password authentication and FTP with write access (already done)
2. I need another user `resources` without home directory (already done)
3. I need the user `resources` to have read access to `/var/www/resources` (tried with `user_config_dir` and `local_root=/var/www/resources` without success (500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/resources))
4. I need the user `resources` to have access without a password (don't even know how to do it).

All that without anonymous access and users jailed to their directories.

I know that this configuration is very popular but I don't seem to find how to implement it with vsftpd. Any ideas?